# send_request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user_id_type'

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to Python. Facing below issue.

I have below function:

```
def send_request(api_service_name, api_url, parameters, method='GET', access_token='', user_data='',
                 request_header=None, user_id_type=None, connection_timeout=CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, timeout=TOTAL_TIMEOUT,
                 auth_string=AUTH_STRING_AUTHORIZATION, scope=SCOPE_DEFAULT):
```

When calling the function like this:

```
def associate_user(self):
    self.response = send_request(api_service_name=ASSOCIATION_MODULE,
                                 api_url=URL_ASSOCIATION,
                                 parameters='',
                                 method='POST',
                                 access_token='',
                                 user_data=self.payload_for_device_association(),
                                 request_header=HEADER_USER_BOTH,
                                 user_id_type="yes")
```

getting below error:

```
TypeError: send_request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user_id_type'
```

Comment: user_id_type is not part of send_request arguments. remove "user_id_type="yes" and try again.

Comment: Using same function call without user_id_type="yes" is working. But in this case need to pass user_id_type, it is required for processing.

Answer (score 0):

add user_id_type to the send_requests parameters

```
def send_request(api_service_name, api_url, parameters, method='GET', access_token='', user_data='',
             request_header=None, user_id_type=None, connection_timeout=CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, timeout=TOTAL_TIMEOUT,
             auth_string=AUTH_STRING_AUTHORIZATION, scope=SCOPE_DEFAULT, user_id_type=False):


    <statements>
    return
```

Then you can use user_id_type.

Also I don't think it's a good idea to use yes or no, its good to use True or False.

It's not a good practice to add parameters when you have lot of them in function definition, It's good to use **kwargs.

```
def send_request(**kwargs):
    print kwargs
    return
```

and do as follows

```
def associate_user(self):
    self.response = send_request(api_service_name = ASSOCIATION_MODULE,
                             api_url = URL_ASSOCIATION,
                             parameters= '',
                             method= "POST",
                             access_token = '',
                             user_data = self.payload_for_device_association(),
                             request_header = HEADER_USER_BOTH,
                             user_id_type= True)
```

This is the right way do it. In this way you can add as many parameters as possible. Hope this works.

warts would be

```
{'api_url': 'URL_ASSOCIATION', 'parameters': '', 'access_token': '', 'user_id_type': True, 'user_data': 'self.payload_for_device_association()', 'api_service_name': 'ASSOCIATION_MODULE', 'method': 'POST', 'request_header': 'HEADER_USER_BOTH'}
```